# How can I find downloaded link history in Orbit Downloader?

Tags: windows-7, history

Unfortunately some of my downloaded files have been deleted, I tried to recover them using different tools, but since those are .zip files it didn't work well. I use portable version of orbit (on win 7), and the files have been cut from Downloads folder, the History in my Chrome browser has also deleted, is there any way to find download history under this circumstances? I couldn't find either the downloading links in search engines.

Comment: Does the download history remain in that downloader? You may find those links in HKCU registry.

Comment: yeah, apparently it does, because earlier if I would download a file that I've already downloaded (even if there isn't the file in Downloads folder anymore), Orbit downloader even as portable version warns me whether I want to redownload it again or not. where is HKCU registry?

Comment: Right click on where? I don't have the file name in downloded tab! I already searched the registry editor, I didn't find anything referring to the file. But how would I be able to search it more precisely?